# Mozilla rest client post json object

Tags: mozilla, rest-client

I am using `Mozilla fire fox` add-on `RESTClient` to test my web-services. Up to this I was using `POST` method by setting header `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and data separated by `&` in request body e.g. `id=1&title=abc`

But now I want to `POST` the `JSON` object to using the same service. The sample objects are as below :

```
[
    {
         "id": 4
         "type":"alpha", 
         "title":"Title1"
    }
]
```

OR

```
[
    {
         "id": 4
         "type":"alpha", 
         "title":"Alpha"
    },
    {
         "id": 5
         "type":"beta", 
         "title":"Beta"
    },
    {
         "id": 6
         "type":"gama", 
         "title":"Gama"
    }
]
```

OR

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "type":"beta", 
        "title":"Sample beta", 
        "children":[{
                "id": 6,
                "type":"betachild", 
                "title":"Beta child 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "type":"betachild", 
                "title":"Beta child 2"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "type":"betachild", 
                "title":"Beta child 3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

OR

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "type":"beta", 
        "title":"Sample beta", 
        "children":[{
                "id": 6,
                "type":"betachild", 
                "title":"Beta child 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "type":"betachild", 
                "title":"Beta child 2"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "type":"betachild", 
                "title":"Beta child 3"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id": 9,
        "type":"beta", 
        "title":"Sample gama", 
        "children":[{
                "id": 10,
                "type":"gamachild", 
                "title":"Gama child 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "type":"gamachild", 
                "title":"Gama child 2"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "type":"gamachild", 
                "title":"Gama child 3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I pass such `JSON` object in `POST` request using `RESTClient` add-on?

Comment: Why do you set header Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded? Can't you set json/xml?

Comment: @Ushani Yes, I had set it and found it working OK. The only change I was required to do was set the header "Content-type:application/json".

Comment: Great! My typo as well. Just noticed. I wanted to mean application/json except json/xml. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the content type as Content-type:application/json